# symfony doctrine connection flush persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager, flush

"Problem"

In profiler:

- select query
- another select query
- third query

AND NOW I CALL INSERT IN CONTROLLER SO THIS QUERY IS EXECUTED

```
    $re=new Requests();
    $re->setViewed(false);
    $em->persist($add);
    $em->flush();
```

And it causes another "3" queries:
[image]

Is it ok? Or am i doing something wrong ? ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each call to [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#flush`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L339-L356) is wrapped in a transaction.

That means that if your current RDBM supports [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html), the ORM will automatically `START TRANSACTION`, then execute all necessary queries and then either `COMMIT` if everything went fine, or `ROLLBACK` if an error occurred.

You can read more about how Doctrine 2 ORM handles transactions and concurrency in the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html).

Comment: Ok, so its normal and fine yes?

Comment: @Trki please keep questions on public channels. Also, don't hijack existing threads

Comment: how can we check if our RDBM supports transactions?

Comment: The DBAL platform in use can tell you that: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/7dd848b7afdf065966daebcac3c134f90ba2bcdd/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php#L3084-L3092